# Directories in settings not showing when creating a web project in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

When I create a web project in WebStorm, there is a directories option in Settings where I can set up my directory structure :

[image]

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate now, and apparently it is a superset of WebStorm, so I expect it to work exactly the same.

However after I create my web project, this "directories" option is missing.

How do I setup my directories for a web project in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 2):

In IDEA, similar settings are available in the [Project structure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.2/project-structure-dialog.html) dialog (**File | Project Structure**, `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S` in default keymap).

Unlike WebStorm, IDEA supports different kind of modules, facets, artifacts, its projects structure is much more complex, that's why a separate dialog is required to manage it